# PHP strtotime() equivalent for RFC 3339 times in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to find an equivalent function to PHP's `strtotime()` that I can use in Javascript for RFC 3339 times specifically like `2018-05-29T17:29:25+00Z`. I've tried using multiple resources already like [locutus's implementation](http://locutus.io/php/datetime/strtotime/) but none can seem to parse times like `2018-05-29T17:29:25+00Z` correctly.

Comment: `+00Z` is two timezone specifiers smushed together equating to `UTCUTC` and is in violation of the quoted standard. You should fix the input to *not* be broken, and then standard solutions will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

try some string massaging:

```
var dateObj = new Date("2018-05-29T17:29:25+00Z".slice(0,-4) +"Z")
```